# How can I find all files using folder name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I want to:

- Mention the folder in one spot (I keep user-defined variables in one section)
- Use that to search all files mentioning a search string (*{}*.sh)

How can I do this?

This works:

```
filelist = glob.glob('max/test/*{}*.sh')
```

But I want to keep the folder assignment separate.

This doesn't work:

```
outdir = 'max/test/'
filelist = glob.glob('outdir/*{}*.sh')
```

Comment: maybe try `filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(outdir, '/*{}*.sh'))`. Or `os.listdir('max/test/')`

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  If it's 3.6+, you can use f-strings for this.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh 3.6

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Comment: @downshift Tha's returning empty..

Comment: @maximusdooku, ok try the suggested answer and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glob.glob(outdir+'/*{}*.sh')
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of using a f-string

```
outdir = 'max/test/'
path = f'{outdir}/*{{}}*.sh'
```

`path` is then equal to `'max/test/*{}*.sh'`.  Note that we have to escape the curly braces by doubling up on them.  `{{` escapes to `{` and `}}` to `}`

Comment: Thanks!, But `glob.glob(f'{outdir}*{{}}*.sh')` is returning empty.

Comment: @maximusdooku looks like I missed that extra slash.  Try `glob.glob(f'{outdir}/*{{}}*.sh')`